# JDA / Javacord Event Problems

Tags: java, discord, bots

So im having a jda script with some GuildMessageReceivedEvent Events for commands. But if I try to use them nothing happenes, no error, no message, nothing
I have enabled all Intents and the Bot has the permission to send messages

Answer (score 0):

This is because Discord only supports slash commands. That means you have to teach yourself how to work with slash commands (:

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).